# Xcode UIDragSession interrupting audio thread

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, drag-and-drop, core-audio

My project is an IOS audio app.

I'm hearing audio glitches/stutters when using UIDragSession. It only happens the first time the user starts a drag interaction. More specifically at the same time the 'itemsForBeginningSession:' delegate method is called.

Like I said, this only ever happens once. I've previously had a similar problem when presenting the on screen keyboard. The solution was to present the keyboard in the background first while the app was lunching.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a workaround or solution?

SOLVED: I've just recreated the audio glitches in another app (The Amazing Audio Engine Sample app). Turns out it's an IOS bug and a simple OS update solved the issue. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Which API is the app using to play audio? What type of audio source data and the buffer size?

Comment: Hi, I’m using AUGraph and have registered a render callback with the remoteIO audio unit. In the render callback I use a circular buffer implementation to playback audio. The circular buffer is written in C and has no allocations/locks on the audio thread. Buffer size is 256 although this can be changed. Device is the newest iPad Pro 10.5. Thanks

Comment: Are you checking inNumberFrames in each callback to handle changes in buffer size?

Comment: Yes I only pull the buffer size which is requested by the render callback. Actually the callback is pulled by a varispeed audio unit which could request any number of frames depending on the rate property so I have written the code to respond dynamically to this. It's like something big is happening the first time a drag interaction is started which is hogging the cpu and stalling the audio thread for a moment. What do you think? Does anyone else use UIDragSession in their audio application?

Comment: If you are reading from a file in the render callback, that can block and cause stuttering. It can even happen just doing a `malloc` in the render callback. Audio can be quite delicate, so seemingly unrelated things like UI events can cause hiccups if your render callback isn't well optimized.

Comment: Thanks Tim but I am not reading from a file but a previously allocated circular buffer implementation. Allocation of the buffers takes place on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to recreate the audio glitches in another app (The Amazing Audio Engine Sample app). Turns out it's an IOS bug and a simple OS update solved the issue. Thanks for all your help.